# Google script - compare script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare

I'm make a script to compare 2 value in another spreadsheet, if value in sheet A not have in sheet B, it will be copy to next blank row of sheet B, with for loop to the last value in sheet A. Just have a problem, while value in sheet A = sheet B, the script not skip this value, still write it into sheet B. Please see my script and give me some ideas. i'm the new in Gscript, just need some instruction from everybody.

Data sheet A - left & sheet B:

[image: Data sheet A - left & sheet B]

```
function Compare() {

  var ss      = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Link sheet B');
  var hss     = ss.getSheetByName('2');


  var ds      = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Link sheet A');
  var dds     = ds.getSheetByName('Data');

  var cmpcol  = "A";
  var cmpdds  = dds.getRange(cmpcol+"1").getColumn();
  var cmphss  = hss.getRange(cmpcol+"1").getColumn();
  var ddsmrw  = dds.getLastRow();
  var hssmrw  = hss.getLastRow();
    Logger.log(cmpdds,cmphss,ddsmrw,hssmrw);

  var ddsval  = dds.getRange(3,cmpdds,ddsmrw,1).getValues();
  var hssval  = hss.getRange(2,cmphss,hssmrw,1).getValues();
    Logger.log(ddsval);
    Logger.log(hssval);

  for (i=0; i <= ddsmrw; i++){
    var dvalue  = ddsval[i];
    Logger.log(dvalue);

    for (j=0; j <= hssmrw; j++){
      var hvalue = hssval[j];
      Logger.log(hvalue);
      if (hvalue == dvalue){
        break;}

      else {
        hss.getRange('A' + ((hssmrw+1))).setValue(dvalue);
        hssmrw++;
        Logger.log(hssmrw);
        break;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your naming a little bit confusing and also your code seemed a little bit off. So I rewrote your function with a different variable naming to make it easier to understand.

So there are `A` sheet and `B` sheet. We get both of them and then use of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to look for values of `A` in `B`.

```
function Compare() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var aSheet = ss.getSheetByName("A");
  var bSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");

  var cmpcol  = "A";

  var colA  = aSheet.getRange(cmpcol+"1").getColumn();
  var colB  = bSheet.getRange(cmpcol+"1").getColumn();

  var lstRowA  = aSheet.getLastRow();
  var lstRowB  = bSheet.getLastRow();

  // Usage of `flat` to get a single array instead of Object[][]
  var aValues  = aSheet.getRange(3,colA,lstRowA,1).getValues().flat();
  var bValues  = bSheet.getRange(2,colB,lstRowB,1).getValues().flat();

  Logger.log(aValues);
  Logger.log(bValues);

  for(var i=0; i<aValues.length; i++){

    // Value from A that we have to look in B
    var aValue = aValues[i];

    // Usind `indexOf` to look in B array
    var indx = bValues.indexOf(aValue, 0);
    Logger.log(indx);

    // What to do when the value in A does NOT exist in B
    if(indx == -1){
      bSheet.appendRow([aValue]);
    }

    // Skip loop when the value in A exists in B
    else{
      continue
    }
  }
}
```

Also as [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) return an array of array (`Object[][]`) I used [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to be able to use `indexOf`.